# Java Concurrency In Practice. Listing 5.6

Tags: java, concurrency

In Java Concurrency in Practice author gives the following example of a not-thread safe class, that behind the scenes invokes iterator on a `set` object and if multiple threads are involved, this may cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This is understood, one thread is modifying the collection, the other is iterating over it and, - boom!

What I do not understand, - the author is saying that this code can be fixed by wrapping a `HashSet` with `Collections.synchronizedSet()`. How would this fix a problem? Even though access to all the methods will be synchronized and guarded by the same intrinsic lock, once the iterator object is obtained, there is no guarantee that the other thread won't modify the collection once an iteration is being made.

Quote from the book:

> If HiddenIterator wrapped the HashSet with a synchronizedSet, encapsulating the synchronization, this sort of error would not occur.

```
public class HiddenIterator {

    //Solution : 
    //If HiddenIterator wrapped the HashSet with a synchronizedSet, encapsulating the synchronization, 
    //this sort of error would not occur. 
    //@GuardedBy("this") 
    private final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public synchronized void add(Integer i) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    public synchronized void remove(Integer i) {
        set.remove(i);
    }

    public void addTenThings() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            add(r.nextInt());
        /*The string concatenation gets turned by the compiler into a call to StringBuilder.append(Object), 
         * which in turn invokes the collection's toString method - and the implementation of toString in 
         * the standard collections iterates the collection and calls toString on each element to
         * produce a nicely formatted representation of the collection's contents. */
        System.out.println("DEBUG: added ten elements to " + set);
    }
}
```

If someone could help me understand that, I'd be grateful.

Here is how I think it could've been fixed:

```
public class HiddenIterator {

    private final Set<Integer> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Integer>());

    public void add(Integer i) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    public void remove(Integer i) {
        set.remove(i);
    }

    public void addTenThings() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            add(r.nextInt());
        // synchronizing in set's intrinsic lock
        synchronized(set) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: added ten elements to " + set);
        }
    }
}
```

Or, as an alternative, one could keep `synchronized` keyword for `add()` and `remove()` methods. We'd be synchronizing on `this` in this case. Also, we'd have to add a synchronized block (again sync'ed on `this`) into `addTenThings()`, which would contain a single operation - logging with implicit iteration:

```
public class HiddenIterator {

    private final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public synchronized void add(Integer i) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    public synchronized void remove(Integer i) {
        set.remove(i);
    }

    public void addTenThings() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            add(r.nextInt());
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: added ten elements to " + set);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if duplicate doesn't answer your question, will reopen.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. And it is not a duplicate. Please read carefully what I am inquiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections.synchronizedSet()` wraps the collection in an instance of an internal class called `SynchronizedSet`, extending `SynchronizedCollection`. Now let's look how's the `SynchronizedCollection.toString()` is implemented:

```java
public String toString() {
    synchronized (mutex) {return c.toString();}
}
```

Basically the iteration is still there, hidden in the `c.toString()` call, but it's already synchronized with all other methods of this wrapper collection. So you don't need to repeat the synchronization in your code.

Comment: Aha! So, in synchronized set `toString()` is smart enough to synchronize on the same lock like the rest of the methods.
Ok, it makes sense that we do not need additional synchronization then.
Thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, the author is not giving this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited*

#### synchronizedSet()::toString()

As Sergei Petunin pointed out rightly, the `toString()` method of `Collections.synchronizedSet()` internally takes care about synchronisation, so no manual synchronistion is necessary in this case.

#### external iteration on synchronizedSet()

> once the iterator object is obtained, there is no guarantee that the other thread won't modify the collection once an iteration is being made.

In cases of external iteration, like using *for-each* or an `Iterator`, the approach with encapsulating that iteration in an `synchronize(set)` block is required/sufficient.

That's why the JavaDoc of [`Collections.synchronizedSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-) states, that

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   sorted set when iterating over it or any of its `subSet`, `headSet`, or
>   `tailSet` views.
>
> ```
>   SortedSet s = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet());
>       ...   
>   synchronized (s) {
>       Iterator i = s.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
>       while (i.hasNext())
>           foo(i.next());   
>   }
> ```

#### manual synchronization

Your second version with the `synchronized` add/remove methods of the class `HiddenIterator` and `synchronize(this)` would work too, but it introduces unneccesarry overhead as adding/removing would be synchronized twice (by `HiddenIterator` and `Collections.synchronizedSet(..)`.

However, in this case you could omit the `Collections.synchronizedSet(..)` as `HiddenIterator` takes care of all the synchronization required when accessing the private `Set` field.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was trying to understand what the author meant by "If HiddenIterator wrapped the HashSet with a synchronizedSet, encapsulating the synchronization, this sort of error would not occur."

Comment: I have modified solution #2.

Comment: I think Sergei Petunin's answer makes the most sense. No additional sync is needed as sync set is internally syncronizing in toString() method. Sync is encapsulated.

Comment: Updated my answer to regard this fact.